# Simple_Form + Bootstrap 3, how do I target the parent div to set the column class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

My simple_form input:

```
<%= f.input :start_date, as: :string %>
```

Which compiles down to the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="exercise_start_date">Start date:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="form-control" id="exercise_start_date" name="exercise[start_date]" size="50" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

`class="col-md-8"` comes from my simple_form_bootstrap.rb initializer, so all of my form fields default to that size. For a field that just contains a date I only need say `col-md-4`. If I use `wrapper_html: { class: 'col-md-2' }` it goes all the way up to the "grand parent" div which currently contains `form-group` and puts it there which hoses my whole field group.

So my question is how do I change from `col-md-8` to `col-md-4`? With bootstrap 2.x the column sizing was set in the input class like so `input_html: { class: 'span3' }`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry, no. Pretty sure I reverted back to bootstrap 2. I think the newest version of simple_form is compatible with bootstrap 3, but requires rails 4.

Comment: You can add wrapper: false to your input options